# Table to DIV transformation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

I have got a big problem and up to now I couldn't find any solution, maybe you can help me. I have a table that look like this:

```
__________________________________
|        | time1 | time2 | time3 |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| John   | ok    |       |       |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Peter  |       | ok    | ok    |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| Sara   | ok    |       |ok     |
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I would like to convert (in order to do a copy/paste in Notepad) in something like this, using whatever you want, JS, jQuery, PHP, CSS, HTML5...

```
John time 1: ok
Peter time2: ok, time3: ok
Sara time1: ok, time3: ok
```

Do you think there is a way to do this? Hope that I was clear enough to understand what I would like to do.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Anyway, to answer your question, I use a custom made function called `diegoChangeToTable()` and convert them. And it works perfectly like what your desired output.

Comment: wait so you want to go from the unformatted list to the table or the other way?

Comment: thanks for your answer.. I need to convert from a table to a list.. I am going to try it but I think @rounin got the solution for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact implementation depends on the table structure, but assuming the most basic one, this should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $rows = $("#times tbody tr");
  var times = [];
  var html = "";
  var list;
  for (var row = 0; row < $rows.length; row++) {
    $cells = $($rows[row]).find("td");
    list = [];
    for (var col = 0; col < $cells.length; col++) {
      var content = $($cells[col]).html();
      if (row === 0) times.push(content);
      if (row > 0) {
        if (col === 0) html += content + ": ";
        else if (content.length) list.push(times[col] + ": " + content);
      }
    }
    html += list.join(", ") + "<br>";
  }
  $("#output").html(html);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="times">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>time1</td>
      <td>time2</td>
      <td>time3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>ok</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ok</td>
      <td>ok</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sara</td>
      <td>ok</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>ok</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... your solution is brillant!!! Just a little thing.. I would like to write also the content of the cell (in the example is always "ok" but in the my needed can be different)? Thanks

Comment: @diego I see, I edited the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery to select the table rows. Once you select the rows you can iterate through them accessing the inner table data information. Once you have that info you can use ajax to send it somewhere or use console.log.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using mostly jQuery and a dash of native javascript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('button').click(function(){

        $('tr').each(function(i){
            var row = [];
            var datacells = $(this).children();
            row.push($(this).find('td:nth-of-type(1)').text());

            for (k = 2; k <= datacells.length; k++) {
                if ($(this).find('td:nth-of-type(' + k + ')').text() !== '') {
                    var element = 'time' + (k - 1) + ': ' + $(this).find('td:nth-of-type(' + k + ')').text();
                    row.push(element);
                }  
            }

            var paragraphText = '';
            $(row).each(function(j){paragraphText += row[j] + ' ';});
            $('body').append('<p>' + paragraphText + '</p>');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 6px;
}

table, button {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
margin-right: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<thead>
<th></th>
<th>time1</th>
<th>time2</th>
<th>time3</th>
</thead>

<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>OK</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Peter</td>
<td></td>
<td>OK</td>
<td>OK</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Sara</td>
<td>OK</td>
<td></td>
<td>OK</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button type="button">Convert Table</button>
```